# k-nearest-neighbors in caret with categorical data

Tags: r, r-caret, knn

I want to predict a binary variable with some other variables, some of them are categorical. I've set up a code and everything seemed to work fine, immediately. The the predictions were quite similar in comparison to a logistic regression and a random forest. This is my code (I don't think there is something wrong with it):

```
knn.Fit <- 
  train(Y ~ .,
        data = Data,
        method = "knn",
        trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                                 repeats = 5, 
                                 number = 5),
        tuneLength = 20)
```

Now my question is how is this done with categorical variables? For example, if I have a categorial variable with values `a`, `b` and `c`, does the function create three (or two?) dummy variables in the background and calculates the distance with them? And are the numeric variables standardized automatically? Otherwise these dummy variables should not fall into account if one or more numeric variables have much bigger standard deviations? I've thought I have to do quite much data preparation before running the algorithm ...

EDIT:
I've seen that I can standardize with the argument `preProcess`:

`preProcess = c("center", "scale")`

My numeric variables didn't have a big SD, indeed.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to know how knn works when you provide the formula like this? It basically creates a dummy variable for your categorical predictors. Since it's binary, standardizing is not quite important

Answer (score 0):

For categorical variables, k-nearest neighbors won't work. Try k-modes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) which can be used via the `klaR` package. The two cannot typically be combined however.